# Shifting the grid to right and vertical menu on left

Tags: css, responsive-design, bourbon, neat

i am trying to make a page with vertical menu on left and on right the outer container.
Now ,I have placed the vertical strip outside the `outer-container` using this css

```
    .leftVerticalNavTab {
background-color: #313131;
color: white;
height: 100%;
width: 69px;
position: fixed;
```

}

and i have used the outer container on the other div and now somehow the `leftvertcialNav` is overlay ed on  the `outer-container`
How can i shift the outer-container to the right, say `110px` to right.
**if i do that to i**t using css the horizontal scrollbar is displayed.** as the** outer container width is set to 100%.
thanks.

Comment: You're refering to CSS rules which we know nothing about, please show all relevant CSS classes

Comment: let me bring crystal ball for remaining code